# Why Weka snapshot version won't start (or after some library installation)?

Tags: weka

**Problem encountered**

There are two situations I met when I failed to start weka snapshot version with `java -jar weka.jar`

1. when I downloaded the snapshot version and start it for the first time
2. after I have installed a new weka library, and start snapshot again from terminal

I have found error messages as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Failed to invoke main method
    weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:308)
    weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)

    at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:308)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:305)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad access to protected data in invokevirtual
Exception Details:
  Location:
    weka/filters/MakePreconstructedFilter.setConstructed()V @11: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'weka/filters/Filter' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'weka/filters/MakePreconstructedFilter'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @11
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'weka/filters/MakePreconstructedFilter' }
    stack: { 'weka/filters/Filter' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab6 0021 c600 122a b600 21b6 0023 c600
    0x0000010: 082a 03b5 0002 b1                      
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@22)

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.forName(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:198)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.forName(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:178)
    at weka.core.ClassDiscovery.find(ClassDiscovery.java:351)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.generateOutputProperties(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:541)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:638)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:614)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.initialize(ConverterUtils.java:748)
    at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.<clinit>(ConverterUtils.java:729)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.forName(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:198)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.forName(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:178)
    at weka.core.ClassDiscovery.find(ClassDiscovery.java:351)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.generateOutputProperties(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:541)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.execute(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:638)
    at weka.gui.GenericPropertiesCreator.<clinit>(GenericPropertiesCreator.java:166)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.processGenericPropertiesCreatorProps(WekaPackageManager.java:587)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1196)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1091)
    at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.determineClasses(GenericObjectEditor.java:192)
    at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.<clinit>(GenericObjectEditor.java:262)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.<init>(GUIChooserApp.java:748)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.createSingleton(GUIChooserApp.java:261)
    at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1816)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 3):

---

**Problem identification:**
Installation of DistributedWekaBase and DistributedWekaSpark

---

**Solution**

1. go to Home directory/wekafiles/packages/
2. find those libraries and other unnecessary libraries
3. delete them
4. restart weka

Comment: It helped!. Thank you. Furthermore, one can also delete all files in home/wekafiles/. And then restart Weka.